# Не могу отправить сообщение в базу данных с помощью ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

не понимаю почему не отправляются сообщения в базу данных. Проверял без **$.ajax** в консоле хроме, все сообщения отображаются, которые я отправляю. keyCode - служит Enter.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".chat-form").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                var send_message = $("#send_message").val();
                if(send_message.length != ""){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax/send_message.php',
                        data: {send_message: send_message},
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function(feedback){
                            if(feedback.status == "success"){
                                alert(feedback);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Ответ такой приходит

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "OK"
then: ƒ (t,n,r)
__proto__: Object
```

PHP оброботчик **send_message.php** который вставляет в бд сообщения, все методы рабочие security и Normal_Query, которые были использованы до этого.

```
$obj = new base_class;
if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){
    $message = $obj->security($_POST['send_message']);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $msg_type = "text";

    if($obj->Normal_Query("INSERT INTO  messages (message, msg_type, user_id) VALUES(?,?,?)", [$message,$user_id,$msg_type]))
    {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все написал, надеюсь кто-то подскажет или укажет на мои ошибки.

Comment: "В ответ приходит такая ошибка:" - не вижу никакой ошибки

Comment: Что придёт от сервера, если php скрипт не войдёт в первый или второй `if`? Что при этом должен подумать jquery?

Comment: `send_message.length != ""` хммммм...

Comment: @СергейМишин я не верно выразился(исправил в вопросе).  Это ответ, который приходит в консоли браузера при нажатии enter. Вот как он [выглядит](https://prnt.sc/otm889) то есть на 18 строке в редакторе у [меня](http://prntscr.com/otmb3m) выглядит так. Надеюсь доходчиво объяснил.

Comment: @ArchDemon  Спасибо за ответ, я думал, что войдет `json_encode(['status' => 'success']);`, в этот  if последний  `success: function(feedback){ if(feedback.status == "success") alert(feedback) ` что тогда делать?что написать в if последний я про success имею сейчас ввиду. спасибо еще раз

Comment: @u_mulder   send_message.length != "" если в переменной (в строке) пусто, то не отправлять на сервер, так вроде бы мне это все видеться. Что не так?Объясните, если не сложно, ибо я вижу что-то не так. Буду признателен за ответ, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам не кажется что `length` это __длина__, а длина никак не может равняться пустой строке. Длина пустой строки - `0`. Джаваскрипт, конечно, и не такое умеет. Но вы как разработчик должны хотя бы чуть логики оставлять в коде.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в `ajax`-запрос параметр `processData: false`

Comment: Так сообщения в базу записываются или нет?

Comment: @zhurof добавил, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @ВикторТаиров не добавляется ничего в дб, только ответ приходит в консоли от ajax, то что вверху в моем вопросе написано.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо за ответ,  исправил эту ошибка, но все равно никаких изменений нет. Что ещё посоветуете?

Comment: @Остин так сделай var_dump в коде php, где-то видимо у тебя что-то там не так. Может быть даже в данные не так приходят, попробуй задампить $_POST. Есть там что-то?
Ответ от ajax всегда будет 200, если скрипт не завершился с ошибкой.